# angular 4 project don't load css file

Tags: angular, angular-material

In my angular 4 project I want to include one of Angular Material's prebuilt themes globally, so in my styles.css I put this import like explained in the [angular.io](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started):
`@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";`
And in my angular.cli:
`"styles": ["styles.css"]`.
My styles.css file have only that line and nothing else.

But for some reasons it seems that styles.css is not loaded.
Do I need to do something else? Why this happening?

Answer (score 1):

Add the styles in your angular-cli

```
"styles": ["styles.css",
           "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the styles in the angular cli as mentioned above it will also bundled and optimised into single file

Comment: As mentioned by @Eliseo Add the styles in your angular-cli

"styles": ["styles.css", "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"]